# Configure `git add -p` to split hunks automatically

Tags: git, git-add

During git add interactive, is it possible to automatically split the hunk (where applicable)?

Comment: I could not find a setting for this. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I'm trying to automate / make faster the interactive patching.

Comment: Frame challenge: are you familiar with `git gui`? It allows more granular selection than hunks, down to line level (in other words, it lets you add just the selected lines).

Comment: How is this supposed to make interactive patching faster? Won't it make unnecessary splits for hunks which could be included/excluded as a whole?

Comment: 1. Sure I use `gitk` all the time. 2. It depends, if your changes are small but do not fit in a single window as a whole... So yes, it makes the entire commit much faster.